# What is the Regular Expression for this type of expression "Start Date: [Some Month] [dd], [yyyy]"?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What is the Regular Expression for this type of expression "Start Date: [Some Month] [dd], [yyyy]" where the entire month is typed... I want to extract this string and then further process it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how strict you want to be:

```
/Start Date: ([a-zA-Z]+) (\d{2}), (\d{4})/
```

...should do it.

More strict:

```
/Start Date: (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) (\d{2}), (\d{4})/
```

Comment: thanks.. it was helpful.. I somewhat know regular expressions now

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a = 'Start Date: Febuary 10, 2012';
if(preg_match('/Start Date: (\S+) (\d+), (\d{4})/', $a, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches);
}
```

will provide you with $matches =

```
Array
(
    [0] => Start Date: Febuary 10, 2012
    [1] => Febuary
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 2012
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
preg_match(/Start Date: ([^\s]+) \d{2}, \d{4}/, $date, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
Start Date: \[(\w+)\] \[(\d{2,2})\], \[(\d{4,4})\]
```

This regex doesn't directly validate the month, but matches that pattern and extracts the Month, Day and Year as captured groups, so you can validate against a map for instance..

The above expression assumes you want to match the [ ] characters as well, if you don't:

```
Start Date: (\w+) (\d{2,2}), (\d{4,4})
```

Comment: I don't think he meant to match the literal `[` and `]` characters :)